# Kendo date picker date range heading is not correct when restricting to min max date

Tags: kendo-ui

I am restricting kendoDatePicker `max` date to year 2030 and `min` date to year 1971.
But the issue is that when searching year, year range heading of date picker shows 2000-2099 
instead of 2000-2029, but the years displayed for selecting is in correct range. Is there any way to correct the year heading to 2000-2029  rather than showing 2000-2099.

My code is below

```
$("#dater").kendoDatePicker({    
    format  : "MM/dd/yyyy",
    max : new Date(2030,0,0),
    min : new Date(1971,0,1)    
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your code I get exactly what you are aiming for, a date range from 1971-2029.  But lets look a little closer.

Top of Control When Expanded:

- Default View - Month +/-
- One Click - Year +/-
- Two Click - 10 Year +/-
- Three Click - 100 Year +/-

So on this third click you are seeing 2000-2099 in the header, but the body where items are selected is correct with a max of 2029.  I think that your expectation is that the third click be 'full range' instead of 100 years.  If what your expectation is were implemented, there would be cases where there would not be 2nd or 3rd clicks needed depending on min/max; lots of extra logic.  Maybe in a future release?

I hope this helped.

## EDIT

Be careful what you wish for, you just might get it.

```
$('#dater').kendoDatePicker({
    format: 'MM/dd/yyyy',
    max: new Date(2030, 0, 0),
    min: new Date(1971, 0, 1),
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.k-nav-prev').click(function() {
        changeFastLabel();
    });
    $('a.k-nav-fast').click(function() {
        changeFastLabel();
    });
    $('a.k-nav-next').click(function() {
        changeFastLabel();
    });
    function changeFastLabel() {
        var header = $('a.k-nav-fast');
        if (header.text() == '2000-2099') {
            header.text('2000-2029');
        } else if (header.text() == '1900-1999') {
            header.text('1971-1999');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is it possible to restrict the navigation to year depth. I tried to set property depth : "year". But it is not working. Can you help me?

Comment: I went back and gave you the solution I think you were looking for in the first place.  You seemed pretty determined to make it work your way.  Enjoy.

Comment: I hope when you get enough reputation points you will come back and mark this as the correct answer. :)